# How to create custom find files command using fzf.vim?

Tags: vim, neovim, fzf, vim-fzf

I am using fzf.vim, I have set `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd'` to improve search speed.

But 'fd' default behavior will respect .gitignore, .ignore files, and filter hidden files. It's useful in most cases, but not all.

So I want to create another command `FilesUnrestrict`, still using 'fd', but with two options: '--no-ignore --hidden', so all files will be find.

Here is my command:

```
    command! -bang -nargs=? FilesUnrestrict
        \ call fzf#vim#grep('fd -tf -tl -i -u --exclude ".git" '.shellescape(<q-args>), 0, fzf#vim#with_preview(), <bang>0)
```

It is good to open fd and fuzzy search the files, but when type Enter to open the file, there is an error:

[image]

Here is the related issue:https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1454

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found this issue: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/462.

Using fzf#run fzf#wrap could solve this issue.